# jQuery replace content outside html tag and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am sorry to post (I usually try to dodge it) but I can't figure out my problem.
I try to replace specific words in the content of a page with jQuery and regex.

However I don't want to replace words in HTML tags and link.
Example - Here is the original sentence:

```
Let's talk about John. John is a nice guy and rocks. <a href="www.john.com">Click here to meet up John.</a>
```

If I want to replace 'John' to 'Kevin', it should become:

```
Let's talk about Kevin. Kevin is a nice guy and rocks. <a href="www.john.com">Click here to meet up John.</a>
```

What I've done so far:

```
new RegExp("(?!<a.*?>)John(?!</a>)(?!([^<]+)?>)","g");
```

It nearly does the job but it doesn't work for the above example. It displays:

```
Let's talk about Kevin. Kevin is a nice guy and rocks. <a href="www.john.com">Click here to meet up Kevin.</a>
```

Sorry I don't know much about regex. I would be delighted if you could give me a hand.
Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mate!  :)

```
John(?![^<]*</a>)
```

Working example:

http://regex101.com/r/hS2mI2

So in javascript it would be:

```
new RegExp("John(?![^<]*</a>)","g");
```

And if "John" needs to be case insensitive, you would just add the `i` flag, of course,  Like so:-->  new RegExp("John(?![^<]*)","g`i`");

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does..  check the link..  try it.  What is not working for you?

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a bunch pal!! You're genius!!  I'll give it a try later but it seems to be the regex I am looking for!! Could give me a bit of explanation? Any good books about regex?

Comment: Sorry I am in a hurry - I did something wrong but it works!! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Lynda.com - Regular Expressions is a video series that is really good.  :) but you have to pay for subscription. Others have been known to download such things for free from torrent sites.

Comment: Thanks again mate!! You did really help me!! I had a look on lynda.com - it might be a good idea to subscribe. Thank you :)